# Передача данных из формы в представление django

Tags: django, form, view, django-filter

Нужно выбрать данные из базы в диапазоне от `olddate` до `newdate`.

У меня есть форма:

```
class GenereteReport(forms.ModelForm):
    olddate = DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    newdate = DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['typeOper', 'category']
```

И представление:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = []
        default_items = []
        transacts = Transactions.objects.all()
        for transact in transacts:
            labels.append(transact.category.name)
            default_items.append(int(transact.suma))
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Что нужно сделать вместо `transacts = Transactions.objects.all()`, чтобы из базы выбрать данные в диапазоне даты, которые есть в форме?

Ссылка на репозиторий https://github.com/IvanYukish/PersonalFinanceManager

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
form = GenereteReport(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    old_date = form.cleaned_data['olddate']
    new_date = form.cleaned_data['newdate']
    transacts = Transactions.objects.filter(created__gte=old_date, created__lte=new_date)
```

P.S. У `DateField` и так виджет `DateInput` по умолчанию, не обязательно указывать его явно.